# In PHP and HTTP, if I set Cache-Control: public, could the user's cookies be stolen?

Tags: php, caching, cookies, nginx

I have an Nginx server running PHP scripts. If I want some of the scripts to be cached by public proxies for more bandwidth savings, I can set `Cache-Control: public`. But does that mean that if a user is logged in (powered by a Cookie setting), their cookies will be publicly cached and therefore **stolen** by someone else who retrieves the public cache?

How can I tell one script to cache public, except Cookies, when it is running on the same domain as private no-cache scripts?

Comment: Caching is unrelated to cookies, so no they cant be stolen per-say, only man-in-the-middle or non http only cookies can be stolen. The only risk with `public` is that a shared cache may send content that was cached by you to a different user. not sure how that would work though, most likely proxing cache. Didn't add as answer coz i could be wrong.

Comment: Oh, I thought some public proxies cache headers too, and since Cookies is just another HTTP header (I think). So then I need only worry about the HTML content body, not the headers. Thanks

Comment: Yeah a cookie is like a header once set for the path its sent on each request, your right though, a proxy is a type of a man-in-the-middle. If you want safe cookies make sure there http only, secure and use ssl. And obviously dont rely on them for security, store private keys or private info in them.